# How to get the correct extension value in golang?

Tags: java, go, bouncycastle, asn.1

I have a piece of code to extract extension value using OID. After extracting the value, the following is done in Java using Bouncy Castle:

```
private DEROctetString bytes;

public KeyInfo(byte[] bytes) {
    this.bytes = new DEROctetString(bytes);
}

public static KeyInfo valueOf(byte[] asn1) throws IOException {
    ASN1Object object = ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(asn1);
    DEROctetString der = (DEROctetString)object.toASN1Primitive();
    return new KeyInfo(der.getOctets());
}

public byte[] getBytes() {
    return bytes.getOctets();
}
```

Finally, I use the `getBytes()` method to use the value for further manipulation.

Can someone explain, what is happening in the above piece of code?

I have added the piece of code, to extract extension for a particular OID from certificate in Golang.
I am not sure how to implement the above part in Golang. Can anyone share any sample code?

This is what I have so far:

```
extensions = cert.Extensions
    ID := asn1.ObjectIdentifier{2,6,7,8}
    for _, ext := range extensions {
        if reflect.DeepEqual(ext.Id, ID) {
            testextValue = ext.Value
        }
```

Thank in advance.

## Update

So, I tried this ,

```
var n []byte
    asn1.Unmarshal(value, &n)
    fmt.Println("After marshal/unmarshal: ", n)
```

where value, is the extension.value of that particular extension.OID.
But the print statement prints [].

I need to do the equivaluent of

```
 ASN1Object object = ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(asn1);
    DEROctetString der = (DEROctetString)object.toASN1Primitive();
    return new KeyInfo(der.getOctets());
```

in golang.

I am trying to verify the key and signature using VerifyPKCS1v15. If i pass ext.Value directly, it gives me verification error. I guess i need to do the above conversion first.

## Update (30/8)

```
type BitString struct {
        Bytes     []byte // bits packed into bytes.
        BitLength int    // length in bits.
    }

    var bitstring BitString
    _, err = asn1.Unmarshal(value, &bitstring)
    fmt.Println("error", err)
    fmt.Println("After marshal/unmarshal: ", bitstring.Bytes)
```

This shows error as structure error:

> tags don't match (16 vs {class:3 tag:84 length:67 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue: tag: stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} BitString @3

It will be helpful if anyone can share a sample code.

Comment: It depends on what the extension contains, can you show it's details, and the official oid? But in general, you just need to call https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/asn1/#Unmarshal with the right type.

Comment: the first extension contains a key, the second extension contains the key signature.

Comment: Just updated my question with more details.

Comment: What does the error returned by `Unmarshal` say?

Comment: asn1: structure error: tags don't match (4 vs {class:3 tag:84 length:67 isCompound:true}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false}  @3 - This is the error i am getting.

Comment: Then this is a bit string, use https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/asn1/#BitString. If you lookup the OID, it will tell you what data types to expect so you don't have to guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220689/discussion-between-prems-and-marc).

Comment: If you're still having trouble, I recommend pasting your certificate and existing code.